# rcorr function correlation of specific variables but not all against all

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I would like to use the function`rcorr` to correlate variables of a matrix with variables of another matrix but I dont`t want a correlation matrix with all correlated to all.

example data `mtcars`:

```
m1 <- as.matrix(mtcars[,c(1,3)])
m2 <- as.matrix(mtcars[,c(4,6)])
cor <- rcorr(y =m1,x =m2, type = "spearman")
```

```
output: hp         wt        mpg       disp
hp    1.0000000  0.7746767 -0.8946646  0.8510426
wt    0.7746767  1.0000000 -0.8864220  0.8977064
mpg  -0.8946646 -0.8864220  1.0000000 -0.9088824
disp  0.8510426  0.8977064 -0.9088824  1.0000000
```

I dont want this output because I am interested in correlated variables of m1 with variables of m2 and not all against all.
How can I do it?

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean here. Are you just looking for `cor(c(m1), c(m2))`? This would be the element-by-element correlation for the two matrices.

Comment: I take it you want a similar output to `cor(m1, m2)`. I don't think this is possible with `Hmisc::rcorr` as the help says "*correlation coefficients for  all possible pairs of columns*". (and a quick look at the function has `x <- cbind(x, y)`). You will likely just need to subset the outputs to select the relevant values.

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned by commenters, the `rcorr()` function is not flexible as it gives the full correlation matrix.
I think you probably interested in this function as it gives a list of correlations, sample size, and the `p-values` each in a matrix form. However, you could do a trick
and access your information in the second step by extracting the requested correlations from the output, i.e,  both the
correlations and the corresponding p-values as follows:

```
m1 <- as.matrix(mtcars[,c(1,3)])
m2 <- as.matrix(mtcars[,c(4,6)])

library(Hmisc)
cor <- rcorr(y =m1,x =m2, type = "spearman")


# extract only your correlations of interest
my_cor<-cor$r[c("hp","wt"),c("mpg","disp")]
my_cor
        mpg      disp
hp -0.8946646 0.8510426
wt -0.8864220 0.8977064

#likewise, you could extract the corresponding p-values of your correlations of interest

my_pval<-cor$P[c("hp","wt"),c("mpg","disp")]
my_pval
       mpg         disp
hp 5.085932e-12 6.791336e-10
wt 1.487610e-11 3.346212e-12
```

you could also do directly on the main output of `rcorr()` to filter values  :

```
cor$r<-cor$r[c("hp","wt"),c("mpg","disp")]
cor$P<-cor$P[c("hp","wt"),c("mpg","disp")]
cor$n<-cor$n[c("hp","wt"),c("mpg","disp")]
```

hope it could helps

Comment: Yes! Thanks!  In the end, I did it in this way and I got the matrix that I wanted! To bad the function is not flexible..